# While using Fragments, preferences don't show up

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to add settings based on "Basic Activity" Template, I was trying to follow tutorials but my preferences just don't show on the emulator screen. It's my second project in Kotlin so please be nice to me. Here is the code I wrote:

*Main_Activity.kt*

```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SETTINGS)
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

*SettingsActivity.kt*

```
package com.example.travelbuddy

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
    }

    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }


}
```

*res/layout/activity_settings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

*res/xml/preferences.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Photo overlay settings">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="font_size"
            android:title="Font size"
            android:summary="Change font size on your photos"
            />
        <ListPreference
            android:key="font_color"
            android:title="Font Color"
            android:entries="@array/fontColors"
            android:entryValues="@array/fontColorsValues"
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>
<!--    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Location Settings">-->
<!--        <SeekBarPreference-->
<!--            android:defaultValue="1"-->
<!--            android:key="reminder_radius"-->
<!--            android:title="Reminder radius"-->
<!--            android:summary="Set the radius of the reminder radar"-->
<!--            />-->
<!--    </PreferenceCategory>-->
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution:

1. I moved SettingsFragment class to separate class
2. I've added method onViewCreated in SettingsFragment.kt

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

       setDivider(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
       setDividerHeight(0)
   }
```

and somehow it worked!